# Variable added to ModelAndView seems to disappear

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I'm trying to get a file upload page in my Spring MVC/jsp project and I've got the files uploading correctly.. it outputs the filenames in the log files, and then I add the filenames to the ModelAndView and when I try to access them in the view (.jsp file) they just seem to not exist.. but another object that I added does..

Here's the Controller where I'm adding the filenames to the ModelAndView:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFiles.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String save(@ModelAttribute Token token, @ModelAttribute("uploadForm") FileUpload fileUpload, ModelAndView mav)
{
    List<MultipartFile> files = fileUpload.getFiles();

    List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    if(files != null && files.size() > 0)
    {
        for(MultipartFile file : files)
        {
            if(!file.isEmpty())
            {
                fileNames.add(file.getOriginalFilename());
                logger.info("Got file with name: " + file.getOriginalFilename());
            }
        }

        logger.info("Total filenames: " + fileNames.size());
    }

    mav.addObject("files",fileNames);
    mav.addObject("token",token);
    return "etl/EtlUploadSuccess";
}
```

The log output is showing that it's working:

```
09:51:09,072 INFO  [Controller] [http-bio-8080-exec-4] Got file with name: ExcelFileOne.xlsx
09:51:09,085 INFO  [Controller] [http-bio-8080-exec-4] Got file with name: ExcelFileTwo.xls
09:51:09,096 INFO  [Controller] [http-bio-8080-exec-4] Total filenames: 2
```

Here's a snippet of the code for the success page, where it should be displaying the filesnames:

```
    <p>The following files have been uploaded successfully with the token ${token.name}:</p>
    <c:forEach items="${files}" var="file">
        ${file}<br/>
    </c:forEach>
```

The page displays:

```
The following files have been uploaded successfully with the token testToken:
```

Annnd that's it... I'm stumped as to why the filenames aren't displaying...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the method signature to return the ModelAndView, like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFiles.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView save(@ModelAttribute Token token, @ModelAttribute("uploadForm")    FileUpload fileUpload) 
{
    List<MultipartFile> files = fileUpload.getFiles();

    List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    if(files != null && files.size() > 0)
    {
        for(MultipartFile file : files)
        {
            if(!file.isEmpty())
            {
                fileNames.add(file.getOriginalFilename());
            logger.info("Got file with name: " + file.getOriginalFilename());
            }
        }

        logger.info("Total filenames: " + fileNames.size());
    }

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("etl/EtlUploadSuccess");
    mav.addObject("files",fileNames);
    mav.addObject("token",token);
    return mav;
}
```

**Note** I have also removed the ModelAndView parameter to the method

Answer (score 0):

It only displays when its not empty, so maybe the file is empty?

```
if(!file.isEmpty()) {
    fileNames.add(file.getOriginalFilename());
    logger.info("Got file with name: " + file.getOriginalFilename());
}
```

Just a guess.

Comment: The OP wouldn't have logged two files.

Comment: Nah both files definitely have data in them. And it is hitting that line, as you can see by the console output: Got file with name: ExcelFileOne.xlsx

Comment: I understood that files disappear.

Comment: Where do you return your ModelAndView to? Because you have that mav instance but does it get to the jspx?

Comment: I believe it does, as the Token does get to the jsp file.

Comment: @JDiPierro Since you do have it, try setting the view name in the MAV and returning that.

Comment: That worked!! Thanks Sotirios! Ayub answered the same below, I accepted it. If you want to submit and answer I'll change it over to yours as you did suggest it first.

Comment: @JDiPierro Don't worry about it. Happy you found your solution.